# Reversing MySQL result in php

Tags: php, mysql, reverse

I need to reverse result from mysql query, but i cannot use ORDER BY xxx ASC/DESC, and I dont want to create new array from fetch_assoc and run through it second time.
Is there any way to do it different way? Or select top 10 records, then in ajax call next top 10 records under previous records.

Comment: Why would you not be able to change the direction of the result set with MySQL directly? That seems illogical (on many levels).

Comment: `array_reverse` and `array_slice` seem to be your friends then... But not being able to alter the query seems silly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may look at the [mysql_data_seek](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php), there is even example for feetching rows in reverse order.

Answer (score 3):

Store your results in an array and use [array_reverse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) to reverse the order of the results.